# Is this a bimonad on Set?

Tags: category-theory

I am attempting to show that the following is a bimonad.  Bimonads are [defined here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1163).

Can someone say if this is a both a monad and comonad and can someone show if this has a mixed distributive law?  Is it the case that the endofunctors $-\cdot F$, $F\cdot-$ preserve equalizers?

$$(F, \mu, \nu, \eta, \phi)$$

The endofunctor is

$$F : SET \rightarrow SET$$

and is diagonal.  As pointed out in the comments, F(X) is supposed to be the diagonal subset of X×X.

So, if,

$$X \in Obj(SET)$$

and

$$X=(a,b,c)$$

then

$$F:(a,b,c) \rightarrow ((a,a),(b,b),(c,c))$$

Now for the natural transformations:

$$\eta : 1_{SET} \rightarrow F$$

Example,

$$ \eta : a \rightarrow (a,a) $$

Next,

$$\mu : F^2 \rightarrow F$$

Example,

$$((a,a),(a,a)) \rightarrow (a,a)$$

Next,

$$\nu : F \rightarrow 1_{SET}$$

I am taking this as the right projection map.

Example,

$$\nu : (a,a) \rightarrow a$$

Next,

$$\phi : F \rightarrow F^2 $$

Example,

$$\phi : (a,a) \rightarrow ((a,a),(a,a))$$

Comment: Your definitions are very unclear throughout, and seemingly self-contradictory. For example, what does $F : x \to (x,x)$ mean? Are you saying that if $x$ is a set, then $F(x) = (x,x)$? And why do you say $F((a,b,c)) =((a,a),(b,b),(c,c))$ rather than $((a,b,c),(a,b,c))$ as the formula you gave would say?  How are you interpreting $(x,x)$ as an object of SET anyways? As a Kuratowski ordered pair? Then you're simply saying that $F(x)$ is a terminal object. What does $F$ do to morphisms? You say $\eta : a \to (a,a)$, but is clearly means something much different than $F : x \to (x,x)$. And so on

Comment: I think $F(X)$ is supposed to be the diagonal subset of $X\times X$, so that all these natural transformations are just evident isomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "bimonad" is a categorical property; e.g. it's preserved by any relevant applications of equivalences of categories or isomorphisms of functors that may arise.

Let $I$ be the identity functor on **Set**. Judging by the edit/comments, the functor $F$ you define is naturally isomorphic to $I$; in fact, the $\eta$ you define is the obvious natural isomorphism between them.

If $\iota$ is the identity natural transformation of $I$, then your question is just a thin disguise over asking if $(I, \iota, \iota, \iota, \iota)$ is a bimonad. I assume this example is trivial enough for you to self-answer.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't actually done the arithmetic to check if transporting your five-tuple along $\eta$ really does give $\iota$ for the four structure natural transformations.